# Shopify local theme development environment in 2018

Tags: workflow, shopify, development-environment, shopify-template

Anybody knows about updates in Shopify local theme development? How to configure workflow. I would like to have local copy of the theme, use for edit Microsoft Code and when I click save button, changes should be to deploy in Shopify and browser preview windows updated automatically. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The Shopify Theme gem and Slate system are both designed so that you can:

- create code with your favourite editor and use a DVCS like git.
- they provide watchers so that any edits are auto uploaded to a theme with an ID

This way you get to write theme code, and watch your edits on a preview theme (or live one, you choose)

Since this is also hooked into a DVCS you are free to work on a team too. Works for all modern platforms and for anyone with basic developer skills.